# In Wix, how can I pass a list of .net types to a managed custom action?

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

In my install, I'm installing several .net class libraries that essentially act as plugins for a third party system outside of my control. For each type, I'm required to call a `Register()` function in the third party API to tell it my type exists.

I have authored a WiX managed custom action to do this, but currently I am hard-coding the types I need to register within the custom action. That seems like a code smell. I would like to make my custom action more general purpose, so I can re-use it in other installers and I don't have to change it each time I add, rename or remove a type.

Is there a way I could pass the .net types into the custom action somehow? I gather custom actions should be data driven, and that seems like a good approach and achieves what I want to do - but how do I get that data into the custom action?

Comment: FYI, that's an awesome question to ask as it takes you to the next level of understanding MSI.  Very few candidates that I interview at my day job understand are at this level.  Congrats!

Comment: Hehe, thanks Christopher. Maybe you should offer me a job ;-)

Comment: I do have some open reqs. :)

Answer (score 1):

Properly authored custom actions should be both data driven (declarative) and transactional just like all the built in Windows Installer standard actions and tables.  This separates the "what to do" from the "how to do it"  and allows consumers of the MSI to see what is being done and potentially transform it to meet their needs.

Checkout:

[Beam Me Up: Using JSON to serialize CustomActionData](http://blog.iswix.com/2011/10/beam-me-up-using-json-to-serialize.html)

You don't have to use JSON.  That part was just meant to show how to pass large sets of complicated data to deferred custom actions.

Also review:

[Installation Phases and In-Script Execution Options for Custom Actions in Windows Installer](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/)

Comment: Yes. And in a WiX world, you could (if it's worth the effort) also create an extension.  Basically you create an XSD and a DLL that WiX uses at build table to transform to custom tables and automated insertion of the custom actions.  This is basically how various custom action patterns in Util, IIS and others work.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a config file with Json, XML, key-value pairs, etc.  If your custom action is deferred, then the file will be installed and readable.  You can just deserialize the data and call your functions using reflection.